# Data formatting in SQL (Convert minutes into HH:MM format)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to display [Total Service Time ] in HH:Min format (Currently values in minutes)?

Query :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  dbo.sectn_dept.sectn_sc AS Customer,  MONTH(dbo.incident.date_logged) AS Month_Number, DATENAME(month,    dbo.incident.date_logged) AS Month, YEAR(dbo.incident.date_logged) AS Year, 
dbo.incident.incident_ref PM_ref,   dbo.product.product_n "Product",    dbo.item.item_n "Item",
dbo.bldng_room.bldng_room_sc,   dbo.assyst_usr.assyst_usr_n,    dbo.incident.last_action_date "Last Action",
Status=case dbo.incident.inc_status when 'c' then 'Closed' when 'o' then 'Open' else 'Resolved' end,
CASE dbo.act_reg.act_type_sc WHEN 'ADD_ATTCHMNTS' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Attachmnet    ,
    (select    cast(total / 60 as varchar(8)) + ':' + cast(total % 60 as varchar(2)) 
    from (  select      cast(sum(AR.[Travel Time] + AR.[Total Productive Time]) as int) as total from      dbo.vAction_Reg as AR ) T) AS [Total Service Time]
FROM         dbo.bldng INNER JOIN
dbo.site ON dbo.bldng.site_id = dbo.site.site_id INNER JOIN
dbo.incident INNER JOIN dbo.item ON dbo.incident.item_id = dbo.item.item_id INNER JOIN
dbo.product ON dbo.item.product_id = dbo.product.product_id INNER JOIN
dbo.sectn_dept ON dbo.incident.sectn_dept_id = dbo.sectn_dept.sectn_dept_id INNER JOIN
dbo.inc_cat ON dbo.incident.inc_cat_id = dbo.inc_cat.inc_cat_id INNER JOIN
dbo.inc_major ON dbo.inc_cat.inc_major_id = dbo.inc_major.inc_major_id  INNER JOIN
dbo.bldng_room ON dbo.incident.bldng_room_id = dbo.bldng_room.bldng_room_id ON dbo.bldng.bldng_id = dbo.bldng_room.bldng_id INNER JOIN
dbo.prod_cls ON dbo.product.prod_cls_id = dbo.prod_cls.prod_cls_id      inner JOIN
dbo.assyst_usr ON dbo.incident.ass_usr_id = dbo.assyst_usr.assyst_usr_id    LEFT OUTER Join
dbo.vAction_Reg on dbo.incident.incident_id=dbo.vAction_Reg.incident_id         inner JOIN
dbo.act_reg ON dbo.incident.incident_id=dbo.act_reg.incident_id

WHERE     
dbo.inc_major.inc_major_sc = 'PM' AND   dbo.incident.date_logged >='6/19/2015'
GROUP BY    dbo.sectn_dept.sectn_sc ,   dbo.incident.date_logged,       dbo.incident.incident_ref,
dbo.product.product_n,      dbo.item.item_n,        dbo.bldng_room.bldng_room_sc,   dbo.assyst_usr.assyst_usr_n,
dbo.incident.inc_status,    dbo.act_reg.act_type_sc,    dbo.incident.last_action_date,
dbo.vAction_Reg.[Total Productive Time],dbo.vAction_Reg.[Travel Time]
```

Result:

```
Customer    Month   Month   Year    PM_ref  Product Item    bldng_room_sc   assyst_usr_n    Last Action Status  Attachmnet  Total Service Time
DIB 6   June    2015    64625   PC2150XE    123 ABC TRADING SM  Hardy Colar 20-06-15    Resolved    No  291193:46
DIB 6   June    2015    64629   PC2100XE    345 ABC TRADING SM  Hardy Colar 20-06-15    Resolved    No  291193:46
HSBC    6   June    2015    64615   PC2100XEUSB+CCDM    765 JUMEIRA BR-OPP SAFA PARK    Fawad Shakeel   19-06-15    Resolved    No  291193:46
HSBC    6   June    2015    64616   PC2100XE+CCDM   787 JUMEIRA BR-OPP SAFA PARK    Fawad Shakeel   19-06-15    Resolved    No  291193:46
UNB 6   June    2015    64626   C2070RL 7627    DHAFRA-BRANCH   Hardy Colar 20-06-15    Resolved    No  291193:46
```

Need to display Total Service Time in below format:

```
Total Service Time
1:02
1:51
1:03
1:02
3:31
```

Actual Table Data (Dtata type=Money)

```
Travel Time Total Productive Time
1.00    61.00
60.00   51.00
2.00    61.00
1.00    61.00
180.00  31.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to just do the string manipulation:

```
select (right('00' + cast(floor(TotalTime / 60) as varchar(255)), 2) + ':' +
        right('00' + cast(floor(TotalTime % 60) as varchar(255)), 2)
       )
```

Comment: If i am changing the query like below , result getting error,

Comment: (select    cast(total / 60 as varchar(8)) + ':' + cast(total % 60 as varchar(2)) 
    from (  select      cast(sum(vAction_Reg.[Travel Time] + vAction_Reg.[Total Productive Time]) as int) as total) T) AS [Total Service Time]

Comment: if the values more than 24 hours ie, Travel Time=2520.00 and Total Productive Time= 10240.00 then the result should be in 212:40

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL Server, it can be done easily using CONVERT to change into your desired style :

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(ms, 120 * 1000, 0), 108)
```

*Multiply by 1000 to change into milliseconds to discard fractional part*

Output would be:

```
00:02
```

Comment: Please help me how to implement in below query part,                   (select    cast(total / 60 as varchar(8)) + ':' + cast(total % 60 as varchar(2)) from (  select      cast(sum(vAction_Reg.[Travel Time] + vAction_Reg.[Total Productive Time]) as int) as total) T) AS [Total Service Time]